# is there a place online to upload a json file and export it in html?

Tags: json

I have bookmarks downloaded from firefox and they are a json file.
I'm searching for a site where I can upload the json file and then download it in html format.

Does such a site exist?

**THANK YOU** for your kind assistance.

**(Every time I do a search for this question, your site comes up.)**

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a site that will do this online, but I do know of a few other ways:

- You could restore them back into a Firefox profile and then export them as HTML from there, like this: [image]
- You could download and run a program like https://github.com/andreax79/json2html-bookmarks to convert them locally
- You could use JavaScript to convert them in-browser, though not with an actual site, like this: [Quick and dirty way to parse a mozilla firefox json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211831/quick-and-dirty-way-to-parse-a-mozilla-firefox-json-file)

Comment: (You could restore them back into a Firefox profile and then export them as HTML from there)   ...I like this but you can only upload html. That's why I'm having a problem. They would only let me output my bookmarks in json and then when I go to import them, you cannot import json....how odd is that?

Comment: I just added a picture. Do you not have that option?

Comment: My old firefox only let me backup in json. so I backed it up before i refreshed my firefox. Then it come  up with no bookmarks. So I thought I had it covered because I had downloaded what they would give me. Now with the updated firefox, I need it to be html to import the file ...and it's json. I tried to restore to my earlier version of firefox but everything I did, did not restore my bookmarks...I even uninstalled firefox and then did a whole system restore to a month earlier, but that didnn't work either...

Comment: What about the "Restore" link that I have? It takes JSON. Do you not have that? If not, can you post a screenshot of what you do have?

Comment: Mine does look like yours, now. But previously, it would only export a json file. and now it only will import html.

Comment: If yours looks like mine, just pick Restore -> Choose File, and select your JSON file. It will import fine.

Comment: I tried restoring firefox but now it says there is not any back up to restore it to.

Comment: TY! that loaded a lot of them! I'm much better to have these now. Thank you very much. That was VERY Helpful!

Comment: When I went to restore earlier, it never showed the json file as an option to import from my desktop. I don't know what was different this time, but there it was. THANK YOU.

Comment: ...now I know what happened. I made a "backup" that's why I have a  json. If I would have exported it, it would have been html. Good to know. Thanks again your help saved me.

Comment: The Python tool you linked worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Check out CodeBeautify, just paste and hit the Beautify button https://codebeautify.org/json-to-html-converter

There’s a lot of plugins and add ons for almost every browser out there; Firefox and especially chrome have great ones as others have mentioned, it’s worth checking out.

Comment: Thank you. codebeautify would be great but my file is more than 1mb (I've been saving bookmarks for years..so it's a lot bigger) But that site would have been PERFECT. That s exactly what I wanted but the 1mb thing messes me up,

Comment: Gotcha, how about uploading your file here http://convertjson.com/json-to-html-table.htm ?

Answer (score 0):

You are making it harder than it is. There is no JASON to HTML conversion required. Go to C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default and find bookmark.file. Save it to your desktop. Uninstall the browser but also check the box that asks whether you want to keep history, etc.

Reinstall the browser, then add the bookmark.file to C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

It will overwrite the file and you have your bookmarks back. It takes about 10 minutes.  No coding. No JASON to HTML conversion. Nothing.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to display JSON, try with the firefox extension named [jsonview](https://addons.mozilla.org/it/firefox/addon/jsonview/).